# How to search using LIKE in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sql-like

I have two records in keyskill tables name "SAP FICO" and "FICO SAP". When I search the record with "FICO SAP". I want to get both records. Is there any way to fetch this record if I search?

I want this both as result if I search, I tried using like as below, but it fetches only one.

```
    search = "FICO SAP"
    KeySkill.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

This is my Keyskill table data (created like this in table)

```
 <KeySkill id: 50, name: "SAP FICO", relevant_experience: "1", created_at: "2019-01-06 08:48:54", updated_at: "2019-01-06 08:48:54", deleted_at: nil> 
<KeySkill id: 51, name: "FICO SAP", relevant_experience: "1", created_at: "2019-01-06 08:48:55", updated_at: "2019-01-06 08:48:55", deleted_at: nil>
```

Comment: What database are you using?  There are some full-text search gems out there that are pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this would be something like

```
search_term = "FICO SAP" 
terms = search_term.split 

filtered_skills = KeySkill 
terms.each do |t| 
  filtered_skills = filtered_skills.where("name like '%#{term}%'") 
end
```

and then just use the `filtered_skills` to retrieve them.

This works where each part of the original search term has to be present in a random order. So we can just use `and` for all terms.

[EDIT: if you want to search case insensitive]

If you want this search to be case independent, you can rewrite the `where` as follows if you are using postgresql

```
.where("name ilike '%#{term}%'")
```

(ilike = case Insensitive LIKE). But this method only exists for postgresql, so 
for any other database you would use the following:

```
.where("lower(name) like '%#{term.downcase}%'")
```

Comment: Better use `ILIKE` if you're using `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Good point! I extended my answer to show how to do case insensitive searching, if the OP would find that useful (actually always seems smart?).